# How do font apps/websites work across multiple platforms/apps?

Tags: android, html, ios, unicode, fonts

There are apps which you can type text and convert them into fancy fonts. Then copy it and paste with the formatting. Like this.
        !

How does this work? Are there any special fonts for this? How the input is being converted/mapped into these characters? I understand it's unicode. But I don't seem to understand how this works.

Example site: https://lingojam.com/BoldLetters

Example app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.theruralguys.stylishtext

Any tips would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: They're different characters. Like, "T" is called "LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T" in Unicode, but "" is "MATHEMATICAL BOLD ITALIC CAPITAL T". It's a bit like lowercase L and uppercase I, which look similar (and might even have the same [glyph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glyph) in some fonts), but they're not the same character.

Comment: but how is it possible to type in them unless there's a font made with those chars? I looked everywhere but couldn't find anything. For example, if I'm making an app, I can specify the specific font to be used.

Comment: Well, how would you type 我? Either you configure your keyboard to support math symbols, or simply copy paste from somewhere. The problem of choosing a font is a matter of displaying (not entering) the character.

Comment: Related: [How can I type special symbols on my Android device…](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/17994)